# wp_tag_cloud for hierarchical taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, tag-cloud

I'd like to display a tag cloud on a site using a custom hierarchical taxonomy.

My problem is that the default wp_tag_cloud displays based on the number of posts for each category/tag. I want it to sum the counts of the children too.

Hope that makes sense, but to clarify

- Cat1 1 post

  - Subcat1  2 posts
  - Subcat2  1 post
- Cat2     5 posts

Cat 1 in the tag cloud should have 4 posts attached to it, with greater specificity attained by seeing subcat1 (2 posts) or subcat 2 (1 post). Presently, Cat 1 shows 1 post.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to capture the results in an array then loop back through them to correct where necessary - Does anyone have a more efficient/elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I looked at the core and was able to resolve this, answer here in case anyone else has the same need.

[wp_tag_cloud](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) calls [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). get_terms is called with arguments passed from the wp_tag_cloud call, so you can in fact add additional values to alter the default behaviour. Specifically, I can take advantage of 'pad_counts' to solve my problem.

The final call looks like this.

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud(array('taxonomy'=>'mycustomtaxonomy','pad_counts'=>1)); ?>
```